# Facebook Login with multiple completely different domains

Tags: php, yii, single-sign-on, facebook-login, hybridauth

I am building a network of sites, all running the same underlying code (different data and themes - similar to StackExchange in a way). Each site has its own distinct domain name. I would like to enable Facebook login for all sites, using ideally only 1 "facebook app".

Facebook asks you to provide a list of "App Domains". My first problem is that I may potentially have *many* - read hundreds of websites in the network, so doing this manually doesn't seem great. The second issue is that it seems this feature only works on similar domain names (like myapp.com and myapp.co.uk). 
Trying to add domain names gives me the following error:

> [newdomain].com must be derived from one of: Site URL, Mobile Site
>   URL, Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab
>   URL.

I'm thinking maybe to use one domain dedicated to the facebook login. But then how would I redirect and log the user to the correct site?

I'm just not sure how to approach the whole problem.

Some data about my tools:

- PHP & MySQL
- Yii
- HybridAuth

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem.So i just came out with redirecting user to my root domain & when user is authenticated redirect to request domain's main page with encrypted data & a little user's info(if you wish you can provide user info by api access). Encryption should be strong enough & should depend on date time....to make hard for recognizing...& then store data in sessions ,from main page redirecting user to requested page.
In whole process you will have to preserve the url from which user is redirected.